# Manually Linking Facebook Contacts to Android

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

Until recently I was able to manually link a Facebook contact to my android contacts by going into the Facebook contact, holding down the contact under the friends list then selecting 'link to phone contact' (or something very similar). I no longer seem to be able to do this. Is this due to a new Facebook update or am I now doing something wrong?

Most of my contacts are synced with Facebook (or LinkedIn), it is just everytime I add a new contact it won't sync automatically (even when going into Facebook and selecting sync with existing contacts). I do not want to use a third party app, is anybody able to help?

Many Thanks.